# integration of function involve infinity as limit

Tags: calculus

it will be hard for me to represent my question .It is a Definite INTEGRAL in which Limit is from 0 to infinity .It is in form of Fraction.so the Numerator is log x .and the denominator is 1+x^2.(x^2=x square)...i think i represent my question best so please solve fast. and just give me hint to solve .My all try fail that is given  in comment

Comment: Is your integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
????

Comment: it is logx÷1+x^2

Comment: i used integration by parts in which tan-x÷x form comes which us know what a furthermore problem...also a term comes logxtan-x in which infinity can't be put in logx also 0 can't be put(tan-x is a inverse function

Answer (score 1):

Note that an integral with $\infty$ as a limit is an [improper integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). These integrals are normally evaluated as:
$$\int_a^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$$
That is, evaluate the integral with $b$ and then take the limit of $b$ to $\infty$. A similar thing can be done if the lower limit is $-\infty$. Try to grasp the most you can from the wiki link.

For your specific question, let's do the same:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}I(b)$$
where $I(b)$ is the integral evaluated onto $b$, that is,
$$I(b)=\int_0^b\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

So, first solve the integral $I(b)$ and then take the limit to find your answer.

If you need more help, I'll gladly try to help you.

Comment: a big thanx
..as u say. please solve it further

Comment: I hardly believe that the integral has a closed form (that is, that it can't be expressed in terms of analytical functions). Could you add the context where you need this integral?

Comment: i can privide the answer that is "" 0" "

Comment: Yes, but if you put it in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log%28x%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29), you'll see that the integral is not defined by elementary functions. So, the result of $0$ is approached numerically...

Comment: there must be a alternate method bcoz it is a question of my book in which questions generally done by substitution, partial fraction,integration by parts.....

Comment: it is a question of ' Dhanpat rai publication'....author R.D.Sharma.....class X||....volume 2 so if u can available pdf or any else... exercise  and question 20.3.10